# how to alternate between two separate prints

Tags: java

i have a Yes / no checker, that says, do you want mulitplayer, yes or no.

If no, it just launches the text based game as is.

the game is just a series of prints that user the "answers". Im trying to get it so if printWelcome2 is called, then

```
line 1 = Player 1
line 2 = player 2
line 3 = player 1
```

etc

However, if it says yes, i would like to alternate between a clone of the "printWelcome"

```
 switch(decision)
        {
            case "yes":
                yn = true;
             //   printWelcome2();


                break;

            case "no":
                yn = false;
                printWelcome();
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("please enter again ");
                break;
        }
```

i've made the printWelcome2(), as its literally a copy of the first. How do i go about alternating between the two for each print, like a basic multiplayer?

Any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to make a text based game, what you'd want to do is make a loop that cycles until an end condition has been reached.  Without knowing more specifics about your project I can't really help you any further.  Maybe look into while or for loops.

Comment: there isn't a current end to it, there doesn't need to be right now, currently it displays a list of directions to go, and the player then types what direction they would like to travel in

Comment: Then I would still recommend using loops for the directional inputs.  Also you could edit your question to include the rest of your code.